# toggle between disable and enable with jquery in a bootstrap table

Tags: jquery, css, html

I have a table with list, and each row have a checkbox that can toggled on and off when you click the row, i have solved that, but i also want one button to be enabled when one or more checkboxes are checked, and another button that only enables when one checkbox is checked.

I can't get the enabled/disabled part to work

Here is my html for the rows:

```
<tr class="ydelse ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle" data-title="test-title">
  <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  <td>This is a line title example</td>
</tr>
```

This is buttons in html/bootstrap:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default ydelse-btn" id="sletydelse" disabled="disabled">SLET</a> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default ydelse-btn" id="redigerydelse" disabled="disabled">REDIGER</a>                                       
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-5 pull-right">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default ydelse-btn pull-right">OPRET NY</a>                                      
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is my jquery:

```
$('table tbody tr').click(function(event) {
  if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
    $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
  }

  if ($(':checkbox', this).prop("checked")) {
    valgte++;
  } else {
    valgte--;
  }

  console.log(valgte);

  if (valgte > 0) {
    $('#sletydelse').prop("disabled", false);
    $('#redigerydelse').prop("disabled", false);
    console.log($('#sletydelse').prop("disabled"));
  } else if (valgte > 1) {
    $('#redigerydelse').prop("disabled", true);
  }

  if (valgte == 0) {
    $('#sletydelse').prop("disabled", true);
    $('#redigerydelse').prop("disabled", true);
  }

  console.log(valgte);  
});
```

Can anyone please guide me in the right direction

Comment: Your conditions are a little weird. You'r saying, 
If there is 1 checkbox checked, then enable them.
else If there is 2 or more check checked, then disable one.
else if (?) there is 0 checked, then disable 2 of them. 
But anyways, here's a code that works http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWbXVj

Comment: Great, thanks. Im sorry if it is unclear, but you solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should toggle the class as opposed to the attribute since the buttons are actually links.

Here's a different approach

```
$('table tbody tr').click(function(event) {
    if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
        $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
    }
    valgte = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;

    $('#sletydelse, #redigerydelse').addClass("disabled")
    if (valgte > 0) {
        $('#sletydelse').removeClass("disabled");
    }
    if (valgte == 1) {
        $('#redigerydelse').removeClass("disabled");
    }
});
```

and sort of working example http://jsfiddle.net/42jevgpo/

Comment: Thank you, great efficient solution

Answer (score -1):

```
$('table tbody tr').click(function(event) {
  if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
    $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
  }

  if ($(':checkbox', this).prop("checked")) {
    valgte++;
  } else {
    valgte--;
  }
  console.log(valgte);

  if (valgte > 0) {
    $('#sletydelse').css("disabled", false);
    $('#redigerydelse').css("disabled", false);
    console.log($('#sletydelse').prop("disabled"));
  } else if (valgte > 1) {
    $('#redigerydelse').css("disabled", true);
  }

  if (valgte == 0) {
    $('#sletydelse').css("disabled", true);
    $('#redigerydelse').css("disabled", true);
  }
  console.log(valgte);  });
```

Comment: use CSS instead of prop

Comment: Thank you for your response, but i go with the first answer